Classmethod to check Initialization of Instance variables in python
Is it bad practice to performm a try/except check within a classmethod and return an instance only if everything went well, or should I check everything inside __init__()?
Alternatively, is there another way?
from hnot import Config
from telethon import TelegramClient, errors


class Telegram:
    """Load configuration data """
    _config = Config.config("telegram.yaml")
    token = _config.data['token']
    api_id = _config.data['api_id']
    api_hash = _config.data['api_hash']
    client: TelegramClient

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def connect(cls):
        try:
            cls.client = TelegramClient("hnot", cls.api_id, cls.api_hash, retry_delay=10)
            cls.client.start(bot_token=cls.token)
            return cls()
        except errors.ApiIdInvalidError:
            return


It's a common practice to have classmethods as alternative constructors with custom validation. However, it shouldn't return None in case of an error.

What could I return?A new different class?

Nothing, raise an exception.

In many cases pre-checking instead of exception handling leaves room for race conditions.
